# LEIs extracting field values from lotus notes form to db2 tables

Tags: lotus-notes

We have any LEI which is trying to fetch some field values from a form on lotus notes. But it is showing missing field error. We have a computed subform in the main form which actually has all the fields. Is it a problem for LEI fetching fields from the subform which is on the main form?

Answer (score 2):

All notes data is stored in documents, the forms are just a layer for schema or view definition.

*Issue*

While setting up, LEI currently only looks at the fields within the selected form. The field unfortunately does not allow you to type custom field names. You need need to use some hack to trick the setup.

*Workaround*

You can create a dummy form on your local with all fields (main and subform) and point the configuration to that initially. Once the field list is populated you can change the db/server name

When the task runs it would target the documents, so if the fields are in the document it should be fine regardless for which form created it. So this should not impact the actual data transfer.